# pass value from form to controller variable

Tags: ruby, api, tumblr

I'm using the Tumblr API to layout all posts of a blog. This is my index method in the controller:

```
def index
    # Keys given from Tumblr API
    @key = '[my key]'
    @secret = '[my secret]'
    @oauth_token = '[my oauth token]'
    @oauth_token_secret = '[my oauth token secret]'

    # Sets the client that allows interfacing with Tumblr
    @client = Tumblr::Client.new(
      :consumer_key => @key,
      :consumer_secret => @secret,
      :oauth_token => @oauth_token,
      :oauth_token_secret => @oauth_token_secret
    )

    # Make the request
    @blog = "[blogname].tumblr.com"
    @posts = @client.posts(@blog, :type => "photo")["posts"] #gets a posts array
    # @posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(@posts["posts"]).page(params[:page]).per(10)

    # # Photography posts only (other types follow the same pattern)
    # @photoPosts = @myClient.posts("YOURTUMBLR.tumblr.com", 
    #                               :limit => 5, 
    #                               :type => "photo")
    # @photoPosts = @photoPosts["posts"]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

It's all working perfectly. However, I want the "@blog" to be dynamic. So, in the view I need a form where the user can input a tumblr blog. I just don't know how to connect the two. Anybody got an idea?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**
Controller:

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @blog = "#{params[:blogname]}.tumblr.com"
  end

  def show
    # Keys given from Tumblr API
    @key = '[my key]'
    @secret = '[my secret]'
    @oauth_token = '[my oauth token]'
    @oauth_token_secret = '[my oauth token secret]'

    # Sets the client that allows interfacing with Tumblr
    @client = Tumblr::Client.new(
      :consumer_key => @key,
      :consumer_secret => @secret,
      :oauth_token => @oauth_token,
      :oauth_token_secret => @oauth_token_secret
    )

    # Make the request
    @posts = @client.posts(@blog, :type => "photo")["posts"]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag( method: "get", url: "blog" ) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:blogname) %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb:

```
<section class="section section_grid has_no-pad">
  <h1 class="is_white is_bold is_uppercase"><%= p @posts.first["blog_name"] %></h1>

  <ul class="s-grid-2 has_isotope">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>

      <% @type = post["type"] # the type of post %>
      <% @url = post["post_url"] # the url for the post %>

      <% if @type == "photo" %>

        <% @pictures = post["photos"] %>

        <% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
          <% @pic_url = pic["original_size"]["url"] %>

          <li>
            <%= image_tag(@pic_url) %>
          </li>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</section>
```

routes:

```
Prefix     Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
blog_index GET  /blog/index(.:format) blog#index
      root GET  /                     blog#index
```

Answer (score 1):

it would probably good to read [the guide and it's chapter about forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

in your controller you would get the submitted values from the `params` hash:

```
# controller
@blog = "#{params[:blogname]}.tumblr.com"
```

in your template you would implement a form to submit the value to the rails app:

```
# index.html.erb
<%= form_tag method: :get do %>
  <%= input_tag :blogname %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

the above code is from the top of my head and completely untested.

Comment: I managed to get the form. I put @blog in a 'index' method and the rest in a 'show' method. I don't know how to link it all together. There is no DB by the way. Any way you can show me how I can put it all together? Thanks!

Comment: if i understand correctly, you have the form-tag in the show action and want to submit it to display the blog in the index action? that would require you to add the proper url to the form. the path-helpers should make it simple depending on how your controller is called `form_tag method: :get, url: controller_name_path`.  see `rake routes` to found out the proper name of the path.

Comment: It is actually the other way around. I've got a form_tag in my index, and want to do something with the outcome value in show. I've edited my question above to show you where i'm at now.

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is with the routes. When I add 'resources :blognames' or something to the routes file, all urls will need an id, which I don't have because i'm not working with a database.

Comment: just use the blogname as your id.

Comment: in your `show` action, i can't see that you are initializing `@blog` anywhere

Comment: It is needed to get posts: " @posts = @client.posts(@blog, :type => "photo")["posts"]"

Comment: i understand that it is NEEDED, but where is it INITIALIZED?

Comment: In the index method, at the top of the controller

Comment: if you want to use it in the show action, you need to initialize it there. the instance variable is not shared. rails is working a "share nothing" kind of way. each request leaves a blank slate.

Comment: I think we have well established that I'm no good at Ruby yet haha, could you give an example of how I can use the input of a form to use it in the show method? Thanks!